# How to data clean and export result to excel while giving every columns a title names in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-cleaning

So I tried combining multiple excels (around 20 different ones) and data clean them then export the result into one single excel using python.

The excels look something like this:

```
product cost  gender  prime
name   price  male    true or false
name   price  female  true or false
... and so on
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

desktop_dir = pathlib.Path(r'C:/users/"myname"/Desktop')
files = desktop_dir.glob('*.XLSX')
data = []

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data)

print(df)

array = df.to_numpy().tolist()

clean_array = [x[:-1] for x in array if x[1]<=20 and x[2] == "male" and x[-1]=='yes']

print(clean_array)

result = pd.DataFrame(clean_array)
result.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx')
```

the code is working now, however, the result excel, 'clean_data.xlsx', does not have the four title names (product cost  gender  prime) and I am not sure how to add them without manually typing them in.

Can someone help me fix the code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

result.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx', header=True)

Comment: The heard is now 0,1,2 and not the ones I wanted for.